# Some Flatpak apps do not display the right Locale/Language on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: language-support, 22.04, locale, flatpak

Flatpak: 1.12.7
Ubuntu: 22.04

Hi. My locales are not respected on SOME flatpak apps.
My system has both English and French locales installed.

**[Steps to reproduce]**

- Install Rhythmbox with `flatpak install org.gnome.Rhythmbox3` (note: it neither work with gnome-software)
- The app starts in English instead of French

**[Comments]**

It seems that the Locales are installed correctly (see Subdirectories: /en,/fr):

`flatpak info org.gnome.Rhythmbox3.Locale` returns:

```
            ID: org.gnome.Rhythmbox3.Locale
           Ref: runtime/org.gnome.Rhythmbox3.Locale/x86_64/stable
          Arch: x86_64
        Branch: stable
        Origin: flathub
    Collection: org.flathub.Stable
  Installation: system
     Installed: 115,2 kB

        Commit: 22586738a1150cb37c580a1ad9d85ef5248ff91a2a4f3908a197d422ec84b1bd
        Parent: 9bfc5512294634881e40d44e44aaa73b7d8756789f1974f6ae64889b5044abaa
       Subject: Update rhythmbox to latest release (ba0aab19)
          Date: 2022-05-03 10:43:11 +0000
Subdirectories: /en,/fr
```

`flatpak config` returns:

```
languages: *unset* (default: en;fr)
extra-languages: *unset*
```

`flatpak config --user` returns:

```
languages: *unset* (default: en;fr)
extra-languages: *unset*
```

**[Things I have tried]**

Using `flatpak config --set languages 'fr;en'` and `flatpak --user config --set languages 'fr;en'` did not solve anything.

Any ideas ?

**Edit 1:**

Running `locale` I found that I had:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 set.

Then I went to the language settings and clicked "apply system wide".

My current `locale` is:

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Is LANGUAGE=fr_FR:en_US:en usual ?
But I still have Rhythmbox starting in English

**Edit 2:**

```
flatpak run  --env=LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8 org.gnome.Rhythmbox3
```

still runs the app in English

Comment: On Ubuntu systems such a `LANGUAGE` value is normal. But the latest information indicates that the Flatpak app misses the French locale. So maybe you need to figure out how to generate that locale for Flatpak. Btw, maybe a reboot would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an upstream bug in the flatpak build

reference: https://github.com/flathub/org.gnome.Rhythmbox3/issues/53

Comment: Do you have a citation for this? A link or something?